# Easiest way to determine if a model formula only has an intercept

Tags: r, regression, formula, linear-regression, lm

In R formula syntax, occasionally a user will specify a very simple model that only has an intercept, e.g.

```
fit = lm(Response ~ 1, data)
```

These models allow for simplification relative to more complex models, e.g. `lm(Response ~ A + B + A:B, ...)` and I would like to have an easy way to detect when the RHS of the equation only contains a `1` and no other terms.  Text manipulations seem possible, but are there any other ways to do this using the R `formula` class or other methods?

Comment: Question seems pretty clear to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer with `terms` is probably the canonical answer, but you can also use subsetting to drop the LHS of the formula and test it against `~1`:

```
fit = lm(Response ~ 1, data=data.frame(Response=1:10))
identical(formula(fit)[-2],~1)
```

- This assumes a two-sided formula
- To understand the subsetting, you need to know that a two-sided formula is treated as a binary operation and stored as a parse tree of `(~,Response,1)`: the first element is the operator, the second element is the first argument (the LHS), and the right element is the second argument (the RHS). `[-2]` drops the second element and makes the formula into a one-sided formula.

@G.Grothendieck offers a slightly less hacky variant (no need to know or understand the internal structure of formula objects) in the comments, using `update` to overwrite the response variable with 0:

```
identical(update(formula(fit), 0 ~ .), 0 ~ 1)
```

Comment: I really like this, an alternative was `as.character(formula(Response ~ 1))[3] == "1"`, but I think yours is a bit cleaner

Comment: Here is a variation which updates the LHS with 0 and then compares what is left to `0 ~ 1`: `identical(update(formula(fit), 0 ~ .), 0 ~ 1)`

Answer (score 8):

The most straightforward way is

```
names(coef(fit))
```

If this only shows "(Intercept)", then you know.

---

Another way is to check "terms" object. In fact, this is `lm` independent. You create a formula:

```
f <- Response ~ 1
```

then `terms(f)` creates "terms" object. Later, `lmObject` inherits this.

Check out

```
attr(terms(fit), "intercept")
## to use formula only without actually fitting a model, do
## attr(terms(f), "intercept")
```

If this is 1, then you have intercept; if 0, you don't have it.

Now, check out

```
length(attr(terms(fit), "term.labels"))
## to use formula only without actually fitting a model, do
## attr(terms(f), "terms.labels")
```

If bigger than 0, you have other covariates; if 0, bingo.